# Appcelerator Titanium - Message flow

Tags: system, titanium, appcelerator, message

I am developing an App in Appcelerator Titanium and I am wondering if anyone knows of a way to send messages to eachother via the App?

Say if I send some sort of message to a friend of mine, which also have the app, it appears on his app, and he has to approve what I wrote to him.

It is not ment to be like SMS, E-mail or chat.

Let me know if I have to elaborate on what I am asking for.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you will have to write an API of your own, and communicate with that. It's something Apps like WhatsApp also use.

In combination with push notifications (Titanium Plus) you will be able to send them to phones. With no Titanium plus you could do it the other way around, let the phone GET them from the server, to check if there are new messages, but I don't recommend that.

But conclusion, write your own API/webservice